# Using Azure Function to retrieve data from SQL DB

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have currently a **WebAPI** which has a **GET** method that reads 10,000 rows from a SQL Database and process to create a JSON object. I use **Azure App Service Plan** to host this WebAPI.

My question is, is **Azure Function App** a suitable platform to host the business logic which the **WebAPI** currently does by considering the amount of data retrieved and the processing has to be done.

Comment: I don't think it's the right service for you

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Can you give us the cause?

Comment: functions should run fast, and wait for the 10k rows to be generated probably will timeout

Answer (score 1):

I think Azure function is a choice for you as it is designed to architect serverless solutions. And in the Azure function document there is similar scenario as yours.

[image]

Also, just like @ThiagoCustodio mentioned in the comment, you still need to consider the function app timeout duration. Here is a reference of timeouts regarding different hosting plan.

[image]

Reference:

[Optimize the performance and reliability of Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices)